# Google Cloud - Error To add a group, you must be an administrator of the group

Tags: google-compute-engine

In the last couple of days Google has upgraded the console in Google Cloud. Since then I am unable to add a new member to manage/access our compute engines. The following error appears: Error To add a group, you must be an administrator of the group

This issue is that until the update I simply added an email to the list of members and it worked. Now this error and their are no guide and to how to create a group or what the group is for.

Please advise as I've spend 2 days trying to let our server guy in to fix the backups and I'm nervous about leaving it unattended.

Thanks Cameron

Comment: What did Google Support say about it?

Comment: Please let me know what are the steps you taking to add a new member? You can always switch back to the old console by going to `Utilities and more` menu and click on `Switch to old console`.

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone else has suggestions on how to do this? Google support thus far has not been able to work it out and guide me through...

Answer (score 1):

Your server guys has provided you with an email which is a [Google group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/46601?hl=en) email and not a regular Google email e.g Gmail. In order to add the group to your project you need to be the owner of that Google group, which I believe you are not and that is the reason you are getting the error.

As such, in order to give access to your server guy I have the following recommendations for you:

1. Ask him to give you the owner access to that Google group and you
   will be able to add that group to your project.
2. Ask him to provide you with the email address(es) from that group and
   you can add them to your project one by one.

Comment: Ahhh. Does that not seem crazy to you? to have to go to those lengths to simply give a person access to my server? Surely theres another way.

Firstly why would they make me an admin of a group I do not belong to? Does that mean I need to ask any person that needs access to my server to create a fresh gmail account just for that purpose to avoid all of this?

Comment: If you are not the owner of the group you don't control the members of that group. As such, if new members are added to that group all of them will get the same permissions that group has in your project which is a security risk. With that said, the group contains users account. You can add these users individually to the project permissions. These emails can be any Google email( Gmail, Google Apps). So all you need is to ask your server guy to provide you with his email (Gmail, Google App) added to the group which is NOT a group email. I hope that helps.